# How to create a process on node from a JVM which is running other node

Tags: java, process, jvm, external-process

I have got an usecase where I have to call python script from Java program. Java process (JVM) will have to launch a process on other system/node (not within the same node). How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is the same machine (jvm and python script), you can leverage [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class itself to execute script directly.

In case of script residing on another box, you can leverage [JSch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) which provides you ssh capabilities to launch process on remote machine.